# Xdotool offset/mismatch when using windowmove

Tags: bash, xdotool, xrandr

i am trying to place a window with xdotool.
Its not going where i want it to.
I tried the following code:

```
terminal=`xdotool getactivewindow`
xdotool getwindowgeometry $terminal
xdotool windowmove $terminal 0 0
xdotool getwindowgeometry $terminal
xdotool windowmove --relative $terminal -10 -10
xdotool getwindowgeometry $terminal
```

and got the following output:

```
Window 62914571
  Position: 10,80 (screen: 0)
  Geometry: 1694x1046
Window 62914571
  Position: 10,62 (screen: 0)
  Geometry: 1694x1046
Window 62914571
  Position: 10,62 (screen: 0)
  Geometry: 1694x1046
```

side notes:
i am using a laptop + one monitor connected via hdmi1 and i modified my /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf to

```
[SeatDefaults]
greeter-session=unity-greeter
user-session=ubuntu
session-setup-script=/home/user/.monitor.sh
```

the .monitor.sh looks like that:

```
cvt 2560 1440 30
xrandr --newmode "2560x1440_30.00"  146.25  2560 2680 2944 3328  1440 1443 1448 1468 -    hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI1 "2560x1440_30.00"
```

any tipps or hints what could cause the problem?

Comment: Probably just the window decorations. When you move the window to 0 0, does it not end up in the upper left corner of the monitor, or is it just the output of xdotool getwindowgeometry that seems off?

Comment: its not in the upper left corner, i can see a space to the top and left. getwindowgeometry seems correct.